# sending email with attachments from an app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, email, html-email

I am aware that there have been multiple questions with respect to this issue. However, I have not yet found a satistactory answer.
I have built a medical app using a whole lot of JavaScript. It runs on both android and iOS. This app determines which protocol to use under certain conditions for a particular patient.
The doctor can send these considerations and an indication of the protocol to use to himself and to some other institution that needs to use it. I use `mailto` for that.
Since there are however a lot of protocols, just a protocol name can lead to errors. So, we would like to send the relevant protocol in pdf file-format as an attachment with the email.
So far, I have not yet been able to do that. However, I see that that there are a lot of apps that allow you to send documents (or pictures) as email attachments, using the available email client on the mobile device (and also through whatsapp and other comms methods).
Does anybody have any ideas please?

Apart from this, another thing `mailto` does not allow is formatted text. It would be very nice if I would have a possibility for that too.

Comment: You will need to call native code on both iOS and Android. But then you can definitely attach an attachment. On iOS you should use [`MFMailComposeViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use MFMailComposeViewController for iOS. Check out this [link](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-create-email-attachment/).

Answer (score 1):

In Android you could use the Java Mail API. A good tutorial is posted [here](http://mrbool.com/how-to-work-with-java-mail-api-in-android/27800).

You can add an attachement like this:

```
 public void setAttachment(String file, String name) throws MessagingException {
    content.removeBodyPart(attachment);
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
    attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    attachment.setFileName(name);
    content.addBodyPart(attachment);
}
```

where `content` is a membervariable of type `MimeMultipart` and `attachement` of `MimeBodypart`